# Exposing api for Python converted to exe

Tags: python

If I have a Python module that sends messages to a server:

```
# client.py
def send_msg(msg):
    ...
    sock.send(msg)
```

In normal use, I have a GUI that uses the above to send messages typed by the user. However, I want to allow the user to make this scriptable - that is easy enough:

```
# test_a.py
import client
import time

def main():
    client.send_msg("Part1")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    client.send_msg("Part2)

main()
```

So far so good. The user can now use their script in batch/bash scripts (the purpose is to allow automated testing in a wider environment which may require other things to be done before and after running `test_a.py`).

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Do some setup stuff first...

# ...then run script
python test_a.py
```

Now, I need to provide the program (`client`, in this case) as an executable (e.g. using PyInstaller) to avoid issues with Python installation/version (and, maybe, to provide some obfuscation). Clearly, now the user cannot create a script in the same way. What options, if any, do I have to allow  the user to create scripts?

The only thing I could think of is to create an option that would read in a .py file. So the user would now do something like the following in their bash/batch script:

`client --script test_a.py`

But not sure how I would get `test_a.py` to run from within `client`?

Also, is there another way to achieve the same functionality?